# How to connect to non-ethereum chain node in web3.py

Tags: python, web3py

I am using web3.py! By default it connects to Ethereum nodes, but I want to connect it to nodes of other chains like `SOLANA` or `BITCOIN`.

```py
# Inbuilt
from json import loads

# site-packages
from web3 import Web3


web3_api = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://btc-mainnet.public.blastapi.io'))
print(web3_api.eth.chain_id)
print(web3_api.eth.getBalance('1GNgwA8JfG7Kc8akJ8opdNWJUihqUztfPe'))
```

This doesn't seem to connect, I have no idea what's doing wrong here...

Comment: It's literally in the [introduction](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)... `Web3.py is a Python library for interacting with Ethereum.`

Comment: That's not true, I used BSC RPC url, and that seemed to work fine! I need to know how to use bitcoin chain.

Answer (score 0):

It will work with other chains besides Ethereum that are EVM(ethereum virtual machine) compatible, which means that a blockchain uses the same EVM architecture as the original Ethereum mainnet and is its clone.
Bitcoin is not EVM Compatible.

There are some excellent definitions here:
[EVM Glossary](https://tradingstrategy.ai/glossary/evm-compatible)